# Scraping titles + links from /r/GameDeals that contain the word 'FREE' in discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, puppeteer, reddit

I'm super new to Javascript and programming in general, and I've found an outlet where I can practice it and share/create features for me and my friends in our Discord channel. I'm trying to setup a scraper that pulls titles w/ links containing the word 'Free' from the /r/GameDeals subreddit. So far, through resources I've found online I've been able to get the first 25 links:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('https://www.reddit.com/r/GameDeals/', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
    const links = await page.evaluate(async () => {
        window.scrollBy(0, document.body.clientHeight);
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1)); 
        return [...document.querySelectorAll('.scrollerItem div:nth-of-type(2) article div div:nth-of-type(3) a')]
            .map((el) => el.href);
    });
    bot.on('message', msg=>{
        if(msg.content === "gamedeals"){
            msg.reply(links, links.length);
            }
        })

    await browser.close();
})();
```

I have a very limited understanding of what HTML classes I need to specific to get what I need and adding the filter of "contains the word: FREE" is a whole 'nother story.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using puppeteer, but someone suggested I try using Reddit's JSON API by using 'reddit.com/r/GameDeals.json' but I'm unsure how to even begin.

Comment: Erik, it's okay to create as many questions as you like, just make sure that each question asks about one specific issue that you're struggling with. Currently it's unclear what the question is really about - finding "free" text, classes or Reddit API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find only links that contain word "free", you need to filter the nodes that you've got within `page.evaluate`:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.scrollerItem div:nth-of-type(2) article div div:nth-of-type(3) a')] // <-- we've got all the links
  .filter((el) => el.innerText.toLowerCase().includes('free') ) // <-- only keep those with word "free"
  .map((el) => el.href);
```